# Can access via browser but cannot ping?

Tags: browser, cmd, proxy, telnet, ping

I am working in a windows 7 corporate environment with a proxy and I need to run a application which uses ping to check a connection.

[www.google.com](http://www.google.com) is accessible from the browser but when I try to run `ping www.google.com` from the command prompt I get host unreachable.

PS: I tried `telnet www.google.es 80/443` and it doesn't work, I already tried attacking the IP but it doesn't work (timeout).

Comment: Maybe the proxy only allows http(s) traffic?

Comment: Tryed telnet and doesnt work. but host unreacheable is more like it doesnt recognize the host.

Comment: The proxy is known on your entire system? Or in your browser only?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is not possible, web proxies understand specific set of protocols HTTP, HTTPS, TCP , some streaming protocols, whatever they support would be either TCP or UDP based. But ping is ICMP. You can't pipe ICMP through a web proxy.

However, you have some alternatives:
1- Ask your IT team to open ICMP for you from firewall, assume routing exist.
2- Recode the application to test connectivity using HTTP requests instead of ping.
3- Add whatever host the application is testing the connectivity with to the windows hosts file and map it to 127.0.0.1:
127.0.0.1 www.somehost.com
This will make the application thinking connectivity exist.